# mysqldump without data without comments without autoincrement JUST CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql

When running `mysqldump -d` I get this format:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=722 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

How do I get this format:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`)
)
```

I'm trying to compare database structures using diff, but keep getting these lines I have to grep out.

Comment: using `mysqldump --xml | grep field` looks like a reliable fix

Comment: Fix for what? It's not a solution to your question at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bsh
mysqldump -d --compact --compatible=mysql323 ${dbname}|egrep -v "(^SET|^/\*\!)" |sed "s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g"
```

Comment: this still gives autoincrements

Comment: `|sed "s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g"`

Comment: @FullDecent now try it once

Comment: Ok, here's what works for me: `mysqldump -d fdcl --compact --compatible=no_field_options,no_table_options,no_key_options,mysql323`